# Where can I travel with a Norwegian Convention Travel Document?

Tags: europe, refugees

I had refugee protection in Norway under the Geneva convention with a Refugee Travel Document, except Schengen countries. Which other countries can I travel to with this document?

Comment: @Ishahak What protection are you referring to? And is the "Geneva Convention Book" a Refugee Travel Document (as per the 1951 Geneva Convention)?

Comment: Do you have any document which will state that you are a permanent resident of Norway?

Answer (score 6):

With a 1951 Convention refugee travel document issued by Norway, you can:

- Use the travel document to travel to other countries in the Schengen area for up to 90 days in any 180 day period without a visa.
- Use the travel document instead of a passport to apply for visas, and travel to, any countries outside the Schengen area except for one.

You cannot:

- Return to the country from which you fled. Your refugee status may be revoked if you travel to this country.

In summary: You may travel to any country in the world except the country you came from, but most countries will require a visa.

Comment: Please source this. I tried to find sources and couldn't.

Comment: @EdmundDantes: Norway and Poland are both parties to the _European Agreement on the Abolition of Visas for Refugees_, which on a reciprocal basis gives visa-freedom for short visits. The Polish page apparently singles out Ireland and Romania, because they are the only parties to this agreement that are _not_ also in the Schengen area.

Comment: I don't think you can go to all Schengen countries without a visa.  Not all Schengen countries are signatories of the [European Agreement on the Abolition of Visas for Refugees](https://www.coe.int/en/web/conventions/full-list/-/conventions/treaty/031/signatures?p_auth=kKaxR7a0), for example France is not.